How to improve visualization during meditation/Japa?
Visualization of deity during nama japa is recommended every where.
Wanted to know any proven techniques to improve that? Any scripture references or books.

Regular practice of Tratak on one or more Sanskrit syllables of the Mantra being chanted will surely begin to open the inner eye needed for visualization. One is to then meditate on the individual limbs of the deity first followed by their smiles, characteristics,  features, etc. during japa. Lord Kapila gives a description for meditating on Lord Vishnu: https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/28/  If one worships Shiva or devi, similar beautiful descriptions can also be found in the Shiva Purana, Devi Bhagavata, etc. If the mind wanders, it should be brought back to the form of the deity.

Beautiful insight, Taraka, I googled but seems like it’s technical. I will focus on description of deity. Just one follow-up question, if I visualise Trishul as deity is it ok ? If u think elaborate answer I will update question as well.

Yes, it's perfectly fine. Once you perfect the trishula meditation, move to other parts. It may feel vague at first but the forms will become clearer with practice. Once you enter Dharana i.e., being able to hold the form in your mind, many beautiful experiences await you.

@Harihara sir thanks for your valuable insight. Unfortunately too many information , no one says these basics. Thanks again.

Does this answer your question?

सर्वत्रात्मेश्वरान्वीक्षां कैवल्यमनिकेतताम् ।  विविक्तचीरवसनं
सन्तोषं येन केनचित् ॥ २५ ॥
One should practice meditation by constantly seeing oneself to be an
eternal cognizant spirit soul and seeing the Lord to be the absolute
controller of everything. To increase one’s meditation, one should
live in a secluded place and give up false attachment to one’s home
and household paraphernalia. Giving up the decorations of the
temporary material body, one should dress himself with scraps of cloth
found in rejected places, or with the bark of trees. In this way one
should learn to be satisfied in any material situation.
[Bhagavata Purana 11.3.25]


Amazing research. Is there any step by step process documented any where ? Or only guru can only guide. This guide is too much high level. Is there any way for beginners?
